# Antminer U3 not detecting in cgminer nor bfgminer?

Tags: cgminer, bfgminer, mining-setup

I am using windows 7. I have installed the driver successfully by zadig.

In cgminer when I open the .bat file, it just doesn't open and gets closed immediately.

When I open in bfgminer it says no device connected.

Command:

```
cgminer.exe -o xxx -u abc.worker -p x
```

Answer (score 1):

From [BFGMiner's README.ASIC file](https://github.com/luke-jr/bfgminer/blob/bfgminer/README.ASIC#L89):

> The U3 does not support autodetection, so you will want to use
>   --scan-serial to manually probe it. For example, to scan all devices, you can use:
>
> -S antminer:all --set antminer:chip=BM1382
>
> Additionally, for optimal performance you will need to set voltage,
>   clock, and timing. Voltage format for the U3 is not documented by the
>   manufacturer, thus must be provided as hexadecimal configuration
>   codes. Timing is provided in the number of nanoseconds each hash takes
>   at the given configuration. A known-working configuration is:
>
> --set antminer:voltage=x800 --set antminer:clock=237.5
>   --set antminer:timing=0.022421